# PHP: upload photos from mobile

Tags: php, mobile

I need to make a PHP application that supports upload photos from mobile phone.
any idea how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, most modern mobile phones are using pretty well done browsers. So I would find out with one of those phones if a standard file upload form works.

If it doesn't, check the `$_FILES` and `$_POST` globals to see how they differ from the regular version.

I even [found a tutorial on uploading files from a mobile phone.](http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapUpload/) And it has PHP examples that look like regular file upload examples.